# Most efficent way to re-use static vba code on any row

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to allow a user to enter a value as a either a percentage, or as a number of hours - with the unused option being auto-populated with a macro using what has been input.

Using the below example if a user were to key in 25 hours, the `macro` would then add a formula to B2 (shown in B3 for reference) to calculate 25% (of the total shown in C2), this would also work if the user added the percentage to cell B2, it would then populate A2 with the number of hours (again using the total shown in C2).

[image]

I have got the macro working to achieve this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range

   For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell.Address = "$A$2" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("B2").Formula = "=(A2/C2)*100"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next Cell
        For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell.Address = "$B$2" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("A2").Formula = "=(B2*C2)/100"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

> What I am now trying to establish is there a more efficient way of
>   re-using this on different rows?

The columns would remain the same but ideally it would work on rows 2 through to 100. At the movement the only option I can think of is to copy the macro multiple times and reference the cells used individuall.

Any pointers or suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused on your main question - The macro, as you have it, works in row 2 (I can see that you're looking to see if the cell address is either A or B 2).  You're wondering how to also have this work on say A and B 99?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do all the rows Between 2 and 100 then use this:

1. Use Intersect to detemine if the cell that changed in in a specific range.
2. Use R1C1 notation on the formula to ensure that the same row is being evaluated.

The code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/RC[1])*100"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B100")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[1]*RC[2])/100"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I was going to edit mine to get rid of the inefficiencies but it would just look like this so +1 haha

Answer (score 1):

Just change your tests to look at the column property instead and use relative references - like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range

   For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell.Column = 1 And (Cell.Row >= 2 And Cell.Row <= 100) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/RC[1])*100"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next Cell
        For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell.Column = 2 (Cell.Row >= 2 And Cell.Row <= 100) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cell.Offset(0, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[1]*RC[2])/100"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```